# How can I refer to the view of a subclass from a superclass in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

So I have a few different view controllers that I want to have login screens over, which are just a simple text box over a blurred screen.  Thus, I thought the best idea would be to make a superclass called Login that all the different view controllers could use.  Here's the code for Login.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Login : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *pass;

- (void) enter;

@end
```

Login.m:

```
#import "Login.h"

@interface Login () {
    NSString *password;
}


@end

@implementation Login

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"In the Login viewDidLoad");
    [self presentLogin];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) presentLogin {
    NSLog(@"Presenting the login screen");

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    self.pass = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    [self.pass setCenter:self.view.center];

    [self.view addSubview: self.pass];

    [self.pass addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];


    if (!UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()) {

        UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
        self.blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
        self.blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds;
        self.blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self.view insertSubview:self.blurEffectView belowSubview:self.pass];
    }


}

- (void) textFieldDidChange: (UITextField *) t {
    if ([self.pass.text isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"17"]]) {
        [self.blurEffectView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.pass removeFromSuperview];
        [self enter];
    }    
    NSLog(@"You're changing the text.");
}

- (void) enter {
    //to implement in the subclasses individually
}

@end
```

The subclass (I am just trying to make one so far) is empty except for a definition of "enter" which simply prints out "login successful".  The only output I am getting when I run this is:

```
In the Login viewDidLoad
Presenting the login screen
```

Nothing shows up on the screen: just white.  I assume this is because I am trying to modify the self.view of the subclass, not the superclass, since the subclass is the thing that is actually getting presented.  Is there a better way of doing this?  Some other design pattern that I am not thinking of?  Or is there an easy way to get around this?

Edit:  I just realized that the code I was running was slightly different from what I pasted here.  I now updated it, but only the blur shows up, not the text field.  Also I realized I had the CGRect wrong, it should be something like `CGRectMake(0,0,100,20);` so I fixed that, and the text field still doesn't show.  Is there a reason that might be happening.

Comment: Is the subclass instance in storyboard? If so can you check if the class of that view controller is set to your subclass and not Login? If you are creating it dynamically then is the class being created is of subclass type or Login type? Also is the textFieldDidChange being called? Instead of addTarget yo should try registering the textFieldDidChange as a notification callback for UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification

Comment: @PradeepK I just checked and the class of the view controller is my subclass.  However, I just noticed something strange: turns out I had forgotten a line in the code I was running (so it was different from what was here) and now the blur shows up but not the UITextField.  It's so strange that it would work for one and not the other...

Comment: The frame of the text field is all zeroes. Try setting a width and height for the text field.

Comment: @PradeepK Thanks! Right after I submitted that last comment I realized that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `height` and `width` and also set your `background color` to `white` . for now it is taking transparent text view

```
self.pass = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    [self.pass setCenter:self.view.center];
    [self.pass setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; // default taking clear color for now
```

Comment: Thanks!  This worked perfectly. (along with changing the CGRect to be nonzero)